# Fullcalendar load on expand

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

I have a question about the fullcalendar plugin: http://fullcalendar.io .
I've provided an image of the current scenario below. The green lines are rooms, and the blue(-ish) lines are beds on those rooms. Currently, im loading all the rooms and all the beds at once(via ajax) but this takes relatively long. It would be great if I could only load the rooms, and when expanding one room, only fetch the info for that room.

I've been looking on their website(and google & stack overflow of course) for this, but came out empty handed. The biggest problem for me is that they have a lot of load options for the full calendar at once, but no option which just loads one room.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

[image: Fullcalendar schedler view]

Comment: You're right as far as I can see, there's no hook which would let you detect the expansion of the resource and use that to trigger fetching the events. Nor can I see any feature which would let you tell fullCalendar to do that automatically. Perhaps you should submit a feature request. Since Scheduler is a paid plugin you might even be able to donate towards development of the feature. Or, since it's open-source, you could develop it yourself and submit a patch. Maybe talk to the maintainers about it. All the code is on GitHub.